# A suggestive opposite color Bishop ending

Tags: analysis

The following position appeared to drive even modern engines crazy!

```
[FEN "8/8/b1kP2p1/P5P1/8/BK6/8/8 b - - 0 1"]
```

BLACK to move will get the following results: Komodo 24.1 64-bit depth 61= 3.46 Stockfish 14 depth 54= 1.12 Stockfish 6 depth =81 1.97 I ask the following position to be passed on TalkChess.com to see whathappens with perfect play.

Comment: Handwaving: Draw. White can only make progress by exchanging a6 against g6, and the resulting position is a Syzygy draw (if Black doesn't try the pseudoactive Ke6 - his Majesty belongs to e8, thus wait with K-d7-e8-d7 when the bishop must stay on d3).

Comment: Doesn't 1...b2 and 2...b1Q win for Black?

Comment: Wait a minute, is your diagram upside down? If so please fix it.

Comment: 1. Where is this position from ? If it was reached in a game, please reference it. 2. Can you translate the computer evaluations into something more understandable ? Do you your engines believe this is a draw or a loss for Black ? 3. Anyway, this is an endgame for Human analysis, not for software oracles, can you tell us what plans you have considered ?

Comment: What does "I ask the following position to be passed on TalkChess.com" mean?

Comment: @Stefano - Can i request you look into learning how to analyze a position in chessbase. it appears you have it as you provided the chessbase positional analysis from their live book.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an attempt to justify "Draw". What should be the plans for White? Obviously wander with the king to...

- Force entry to f6. This would win by zugzwang after some manouvering (play B to c7 and K to f7, the bB gets "scissored").
- Force entry to c7. The d pawn queens (or the a).
- Force entry to b8. The a pawn queens.

Unfortunately for White, the board is a line too short on either side.
Black's correct plan for defense is playing the K to e6 immediately and the B to the long diagonal. Then, always block an eventual Kd4 with Ke6, Kb6 with Kd7 and Ka7 with Kc8. Laugh about the a-pawn running to a7, the B will control a8.